# Finding all members in OUs of the same name

Tags: powershell, active-directory, ldap

My organization has a different OU for each site we have. Within each site is a nested out called `OU=USERS`.

I want to find all members in every sites nested `USERS` OU.

Simply using the following command does not work:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=USERS,DC=*****,DC=*****"
```

Obviously, this does not return anything. I must specify a site:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=USERS,OU=MySite,DC=*****,DC=*****"
```

Is it possibly to search through every site OU looking for the sub USERS ou?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use another cmdlet to get the OU's you are looking for.

```
$ous = Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter "Name -eq 'Users'" 
$ous | ForEach-Object{
    Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase $_.DistinguishedName
}
```

`Get-ADOrganizationalUnit` will get all the USERS OU's for you then you can run `Get-ADUser` against each of those.